# How to use check a checkbox in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have checkbox which is created as below in CI:

```
echo form_checkbox(array(
    'name' => 'active',
    'id' => 'active',
    'value' => '1'
));
```

I also have other fields such as Name which have a required field validation applied. So, when I leave Name as blank and tick the `active` checkbox, then it shows error for name. But it removes the check on active checkbox. I want to keep the active checkbox as checked.

I know about a `set_checkbox` method in CI, but not sure how to use this in the above. In case of `form_input` we simply use `set_value` and all is ok. But with `set_checkbox` it returns full string `checked="checked"`. So when I use the `set_checkbox` and `form_checkbox` as combined as below, then it doesn't work.

```
echo form_checkbox(array(
    'name' => 'active',
    'id' => 'active',
    'value' => '1',
    'checked' => set_checkbox('active', '1')
));
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: There happens to be a bug related to this behavior, which was fixed just today: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/0b59bdd3cd647b44c83e746a5d3d3aa179325df4

Answer (score 1):

You can set this as

```
echo form_checkbox(array(
    'name' => 'active',
    'id' => 'active',
    'value' => '1',
    'checked' => ($this->input->post('active') && $this->input->post('active') == 1 )
));
```

**IF you Do not use ($this->input->post('active') && ....) in your condition it will throw an error if you do not check this check-box and submit the form.**

Answer (score 0):

The checked attribute on form_checkbox accepts TRUE/FALSE value. A simple comparison to see if the value is set will work.

```
echo form_checkbox(array(
    'name' => 'active',
    'id' => 'active',
    'value' => '1',
    'checked' => ( $this->input->post('active') == 1 )
));
```

The set_checkbox method was not made to be used in this style. It's intended to be use inside existing HTML as per this example from the [CI User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_checkbox)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck', '1'); ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" value="2" <?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck', '2'); ?> />
```